# adding "data" options to items in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, intro.js

Hi I am new to datatables and javascript in general and I was wondering if there is anyway to add "data" options to rows and items in datatables.

I am trying to make an intro tour to my site using http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/

and in order to do that I need to add data-info="" and data-step="" options to the item.

So for example when you use intro.js you add items that have "data-intro" and "data-step" options like:

```
<h1 data-intro='This is step one.' data-step='1'>The Changelog</h1>
```

Because data-tables is all javascript rendered there is no way to add this to either the "Show/hide columns" button and individual rows in the picture below.  Is this possible to fix?

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Here is the show entries button

Comment: What does "h1" have to with a DataTables grid listing?

Comment: it was just an example to show that you need the data-intro and data-step options

Comment: But *where* is the "h1" and *how* does it relate to a DataTable grid? What does "The Changelog" have to do with *any* of the data presented in the grid?

Comment: It does not relate to datatables at all. it was an example taken from the intro.js documentation and was primarily there just to show how intro.js works that you need the data-step and data-intro options and I dont know how to add those 2 options to datatable items

Comment: If it *doesn't* relate to the DataTable/question then it's a terrible example and should be replaced as it only detracts from a real problem(s)/question(s). The term of `data-*` tags is "data attributes". What do "h1" or data attributes have to do with "Show/hide" column? *Where* should the data attributes even be (since there isn't even an "h1")?

Comment: Perhaps if you would share your DataTable code with us we would be able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `fnRowCallback` option of datatables to add custom attributes to rows in the table after they are created ([see the docs](https://datatables.net/usage/callbacks)).

```
$('#mytable').dataTable({
    // Set data for the table here
    // ...

    // Add data attributes for intro.js
    'fnRowCallback': function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        if (aData[1] === 'Firefox 2') {
            $('td:eq(1)', nRow)
                .attr('data-intro', 'This column shows the browser type.')
                .attr('data-step', '1');
        }
    },

    // Add data attributes for sections, that do not belong to the table itself
    'fnInitComplete': function(oSettings, json) {
        // The number of elements selector seems to have the id of the table + '_length'
        $('#example_length')
            .attr('data-intro', 'Select the number of entries to show.')
            .attr('data-step', '1');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2f2L6/1/

Comment: thank you so much! this is awesome!! would you happen to know how to add them to the "Show '' Entities" button?  I know that this has to relate with the fnHeaderCallback but I am quite new to jquery and dont quite understand how to find the "Show Entities" tag for

$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "fnHeaderCallback": function( nHead, aData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay ) {
      nHead.getElementsByTagName('th')[0].innerHTML = "Displaying "+(iEnd-iStart)+" records";
    }
  } );
} )

Comment: What exactly is the "Shoe Entities" button and what do you want to do with it? If you want to start `intro.js` with it, see the "Start Intro" button in the linked JSFiddle. It is just a click event. If you are referring to another part of the table, have look the [full reference of datatables](https://datatables.net/ref). You can customize nearly any element after it has been created.

Comment: the show 10 entries button is the button at top of the table it is posted in my recent edit. THank you!

Comment: OK, got it. `fnHeaderCallback` doesn't seem to be the correct callback here. I think it is meant for the table header row. However the `fnInitComplete` callback does work. I updated the answer (and the fiddle).

Comment: THank you sooo much!! if i could give you 100 up votes I would haha

Comment: Hi Jan... Sorry to bother you again but how do you highlight the entire row instead of just that one column? I tried changing this line "$('td:eq(1)', nRow)" to "$(nRow)" getting rid of the "td(1):eq" and it worked but I couldnt see the contents of the row... Any help would be appreciated -_-

Comment: Hm, highlighting the entire row works in Firefox but not in Chrome. I guess its because tables are just bad for styling. I have no idea how to fix this, sorry.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jan! I really appreciate all of the help!